# Modifying enum parameter values in a method

Tags: java, enums

**Item**

```
public enum Item
{
    SANDWICH("sandwich"), CRISPS("crisps"), DRINK("drink");

private String description;

Item(String description)
{
this.description = description;

}

public String toString()
{
    return description;
}

}
```

**Character**

```
  public enum Character
{
    LAURA("Laura",Item.SANDWICH),SALLY("Sally", Item.CRISPS),ANDY("Andy", Item.DRINK),ALEX("Alex", null);


private String charDescription;
private Item item;

private Character(String Chardescription, Item item) {
    this.charDescription = charDescription;
    this.item = item;
}


public String toString()
{
    return charDescription;
}

public boolean take(Item item)
{

}
```

I wrote these two enumeration classes, where **Item** contains items with their descriptions and **Character** has four different Character objects: LAURA, SALLY, ANDY and ALEX, each parameterized with a description and an item. The item may be null.

I need to write a method **take(Item item)**, which takes the indicated
item from the character if the character has that item, and returns true if it is successful in taking the item from the character, and false otherwise.

I don't know how to implement this by modifying the parameters of the enum class **Character**. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumeration values are designed as constant values.
Look at the [Oracle examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) : Day, Planet.

It is not explicitly said that the enum value states have to be immutable but I find quite counter intuitive to define constant things defined at compile time that have a mutable state.
Note also that the very most of time, enum values defined in the JDK (or third party libraries) are immutable.

Mutability seems really more natural and expected for classes.

So I advise to not change their state after their instantiation.
If you need to change their values, using a class makes probably more sense.

Note that defining reading methods in your enum class such as :

```
public boolean hasItem(Item item){
   return item == this.item;
}
```

is valid without any hesitation.

Comment: There is nothing in the JLS (or any other literature I'm aware of) that suggests enums "are designed as constant values" (I assume you mean *immutable* when you say "constant").

Comment: @Bohemian "An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html )

Comment: the *references* (to the enum instances) are constant, but the instances need not be immutable

Comment: @Bohemian A constant which the parts are mutable is not a constant any longer.

Comment: Every enum reference is constant and the number of references are predefined by the enum definition. Having mutable fields doesn't affect the usability of any enum

Comment: @Bohemian Technically, what you said is not wrong. It is not explicitly said but I find quite counter intuitive to define constant things defined at compile time that have a mutable state. Mutability seems more natural and expected for classes.

Comment: @Klaimmore  It is right. But whatever I don't find it very natural. I updated my answer to express it.

Comment: Joshua Bloch purposes using an enum to safely implement the singleton pattern (in Effective Java), which is not an immutable concept as such.

Comment: @daniu the singleton *object* need not be immutable, in fact they rarely are which is why you want a singleton - they have state that must be carefully managed.

Comment: @davidxxx who says the fields on enum instances are defined at compile time? Importantly enums *are* classes (with a few special caveats). Unless the fields of an enum are `final`, they are mutable.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't refer to fields but to enum values. "Unless the fields of an enum are final, they are mutable." It is your opinion. Many things are provided by the languages. It doesn't mean that all of them is a good thing to do. For example, interfaces may contain `static final String` but it is not fine to do it.

Comment: @Bohemian That's what I was saying.

Comment: @david enum values are not much different from instances of normal classes: they can have setters for their fields, methods that mutate several fields, whatever. The main difference between an enum class and a normal class is the only instances possible of an enum class are the values declared in it, which are final (ie you can't assign a new instance of the enum class to the enum value). However, the fields within the enum class are free to change as you need. A usecase for having fields that change might be an Action enum that increments a counter field each time the action is taken.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what you might feel, `enum` instances are not immutable. Just modify the `item` field of the enum:

```
public boolean take(Item item) {
    if (item == this.item) {
        this.item = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create Characters as a Class, instead of an Enum.